# how to inject dependency in _viewimports file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to generate a generic BaseViewPage in asp.net Core to access Current User's Identities.

For this purpose I created a BaseViewPage.cs file  -

```
 public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
    {
        private static ClaimsPrincipal principal;
        public BaseViewPage(IPrincipal _principal)
        {
            principal = _principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the constructor here I am injecting a dependency of `IPrincipal` type so that it gets defined at run time.

Now time to inherit it in _viewimports.cshtml file to use current user in all the view pages as below -

```
@using TWCStore
@inherits MyStore.Helpers.BaseViewPage<TModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Whenever I try to use any property in my view - `ProductCategories.cshtml` the error invokes here

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter '_principal' of
>   'BaseViewPage.BaseViewPage(IPrincipal)'  MyStore D:\Projects\TWCStore\TWCStore\Views\Store\ProductCategories.cshtml  1   Active

I am assuming when I am injecting the dependency then it wants me to put the `IPrincipal` as Dependency here too -

```
 @inherits MyStore.Helpers.BaseViewPage<TModel>
```

How do I inject this dependency in here ?

Comment: Have you tried registering in startup.cs ?

Comment: ClaimsPrincipal is not something registered with dependency injection, the authentication middleware creates the principal from the auth cookie on each request. You don't need to inject it because it is already available in views. User property is intrinsically available in views and is the ClaimsPrincipal

Comment: also probably best to not create a basepage with constructor dependencies you don't need that since you can use @inject right inside the view to get things injected

Comment: _viewimports is just for making namespaces and taghelpers available globally in other views, nothing more, you should not try to do other things there

Comment: @JoeAudette, In all the cases I was getting the ClaimsPrincipal null if I don't inject it. Let me know how do you get claims without injecting?

Also, My problem was solved by injecting an interface instead of inheriting. I should update question in spare time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its late I am writing solution (actually an alternate) to this problem here.

So I followed dependency injection (sorry for now forgetting the help link).

Here is what I did -

**Create an Interface**

```
public interface IAppUserAccessor
    {
        int MemberId { get; }
    }
```

**Resolver class**

```
 public class AppUserAccessor : IAppUserAccessor
    {
        private readonly MyContext _context;
        public AppUserAccessor(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        int IAppUserAccessor.MemberId
        {
            get
            {
                return _context.Member.MemberId;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Register the service in StartUp.cs under 'ConfigureServices' section**

```
 services.AddTransient<IAppUserAccessor, AppUserAccessor>();
```

**Inject in _viewimports.cshtml**

```
@using MyApplication
@inject MyApplication.Helpers.IAppUserAccessor AppUserAccessor
```

Now this is accessible in every view as -

```
@AppUserAccessor.MemberId
```