# Inject a service in all ASP.Net Core Razor views

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection

How can I inject a service into all razor views?

In views, where I need to access a service (which stores localized texts), I can inject it like this:

```
@inject IResourceHelper _resourceHelper
```

and then I can use it like this...:

```
<a id="somelink" title="@(_resourceHelper.GetText("somelink-title"))"></a>
```

Works just fine. However, since I need this in all views (pretty much), I would like to inject it just once - and have it available everywhere.

I have looked towards _ViewImports.cshtml, which seems like a natural fit for something like this - where I already add some taghelpers, like this:

```
@addTagHelper MyProject.Internationalization.TagHelpers.*, MyProject.Core
```

I have tried adding an inject-statement there, but it does not make the service available in razor views.

**How can I inject a service into all razor views?**

Comment: This solution seemed to work for someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45810998/13522284

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add

```
@inject IResourceHelper _resourceHelper
```

in Viewimports, then you can use it globally like

```
<h1 class="display-4">@(_resourceHelper.Actionname().title)</h1>
```

This works for me, as a sample:

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<h1 class="display-4">@(MyService.getname().Name)</h1>
```